# How to convert several characters to vectors in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, character

I am struggling with converting several characters to vectors and making them as a list in R.

The converting rule is as follows:

1. Assign a number to each character. ex. A=1, B=2, C=3,...
2. Make a vector when the length of characters is ">=2". ex. AB = c(1,2), ABC = c(1,2,3)
3. Make lists containing several vectors.

For example, suppose that there is `ex` object with three components. For each component, I want to make it to list objects `list1`, `list2`, and `list3`.

```
ex = c("(A,B,C,D)", "(AB,BC,CD)","(AB,C)")

# 3 lists to be returned from ex object
list1 = "list(1,2,3,4)"                # from (A,B,C,D)
list2 = "list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4))" # from (AB,BC,CD)
list3 = "list(c(1,2), c(3))"           # from (AB,C)
```

Please let me know a good R function to solve the example above.
* The minor change is reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lookUpTable = as.numeric(1:4)        #map numbers to their respective strings
names(lookUpTable) = LETTERS[1:4]

step1<-                              #get rid of parentheses and split by ",".
strsplit(gsub("[()]", "", ex), ",")

result<-                             #split again to make things like "AB" into "A", "B", also convert the strings to numbers acc. to lookUpTable
lapply(step1, function(x){ lapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(u) unname(lookUpTable[u])) })

# assign to the global environment.
invisible(
lapply(seq_along(result), function(x) {assign(paste0("list", x), result[[x]], envir = globalenv()); NULL})
)

# get it as strings:
invisible(
    lapply(seq_along(result), function(x) {assign(paste0("list_string", x), capture.output(dput(result[[x]])), envir = globalenv()); NULL})
)
```

---

data:

```
ex = c("(A,B,C,D)", "(AB,BC,CD)","(AB,C)")
```

---

tips and tricks:

- I make use of regular expressions in `gsub` (and `strsplit`). Learn regex!
- I made a `lookUpTable` that maps the individual strings to numbers. Make sure your lookUpTable is set up analogously.
- Have a look at apply functions like in that case `?lapply`.
- lastly I `assign` the result to the global environment. I dont recommend this step but its what you have requested.

Comment: Thank you for a kind response!!! However, I tried all the steps you suggested, but the last step was a little bit different in that list1, list2, and list3 are "nested list" form.
Further, I need to flatten each nested list and combine them in "c()" form. Could you help me to make a final form as I suggested?

Comment: with your input data `ex` my solution gives except for type `int` instead of `num` the exact same result. Not sure where your problem is.

Comment: Ah I got what you meant. The structural form is exactly same! I misthought the type of final forms is a `list`. But I need to make a `character object` such as `list1="list(1,2,3,4)"` and `list2="list(c(1,2), c(2,3), c(3,4))"`. Sorry for misleading you...

Comment: @EunjiLee, I updated my solution. This is the closest I can get. please note I made a slight change to the lookUpTable (as.numeric).

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you so much:)